# Cannot read property 'getAboutInfo' of undefined at <Jasmine>

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

This is my code in angular, the functionality is working all fine but the test cases are getting failed. Please tell me what i am doing wrong in the code?
The error I am getting

> HeadlessChrome 83.0.4103 (Windows 10.0.0) AboutComponent should create FAILED
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAboutInfo' of undefined
> at **
> at AboutComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/src/app/about/about.component.ts:44:28)
> at callHook (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:3937:1)
> at callHooks (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:3901:1)
> at executeInitAndCheckHooks (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:3842:1)
> at refreshView (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:11795:1)
> at renderComponentOrTemplate (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:11903:1)
> at tickRootContext (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:13379:1)
> at detectChangesInRootView (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:13413:1)
> at RootViewRef.detectChanges (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:15093:22)
> at ComponentFixture._tick (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/testing.js:323:1)

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AboutComponent } from './about.component';
import { AboutService } from './about.service';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { I18nService } from 'src/utils/i18n.service';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { AppModule } from './../app.module';

describe('AboutComponent', () => {
  let component: AboutComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AboutComponent>;
  let dialogSpy: jasmine.Spy;
  let app: any;
  const mockDialogRef = {
    close: jasmine.createSpy('close')
  };
  let service: any;
  const data = '20/04/2019';
  let getAboutInfoSpy: any;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AboutComponent],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule , AppModule],
      providers: [{ provide: AboutService, useValue: service },
        I18nService,
            { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} },
            { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: mockDialogRef}]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(async () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AboutComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    await fixture.whenStable();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('infoList should be empty array', () => {
    expect(app['dataList'].length).toBe(0);
  });

  it('when OnInit invoked through service data will return to infoList ', async(() => {
    service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(AboutService);
    spyOn(service, 'getAboutInfo').and.returnValue(of(data));
    app.ngOnInit();
    expect(app['dataList'].length).toBe(3);
  }));

  it('onCancel should close the dialog', async( () => {
    component.closePopup();
    expect(mockDialogRef.close).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));

});
```

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { AboutService } from './about.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { I18nService } from 'src/utils/i18n.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.scss']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {

  private aboutServiceSubscription: Subscription;
  dataList: any;
  locales: any = {};
  translator: any;
  
  constructor(
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AboutComponent>,
    public aboutService: AboutService,
    private i18Service: I18nService) {}


  ngOnInit() {
    this.translator = this.i18Service.getTranslator();
    this.translator.translateObject.subscribe((item: any) => {
      this.locales = item;
    });
    this.aboutServiceSubscription =  this.aboutService.getAboutInfo().subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (data) {
        data = data.split('/');
        this.dataList = data;
      }
    });
  }


   /**
    * Closes the poup
    * @memberof AboutComponent
    */
  closePopup() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AboutService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

   }

   getAboutInfo() {
    return this.http.get('/assets/aboutInfo.txt', {responseType: 'text'})
  }
}
```

Comment: `providers: [{ provide: AboutService, useValue: service },` <= I don't see where you are instantiating a value for the `service` variable prior to the setup

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: `service = <something>`.  Such as `service = jasmine.createObjectSpy('AboutService', ['getAboutInfo'])`.  However, since the service is `providedIn: 'root'` you shouldn't have to do that at all.  You should just be able to remove that providers line and later use `TestBed.inject(AboutService)` to get the service that was injected into your component.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that you did not mock `AboutService` correctly, you passed an `undefined` to `useValue`, so the `AboutService` obtained through the Injector is `undefined`. You can't use `spyOn` to a `undefined` value.

Here is a working example, with irrelevant code removed:

`about.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AboutService } from './about.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
  private aboutServiceSubscription: Subscription;
  dataList: any;
  locales: any = {};
  translator: any;

  constructor(public aboutService: AboutService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.aboutServiceSubscription = this.aboutService
      .getAboutInfo()
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        if (data) {
          data = data.split('/');
          this.dataList = data;
        }
      });
  }
}
```

`about.service.ts`:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AboutService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getAboutInfo() {
    return this.http.get('/assets/aboutInfo.txt', { responseType: 'text' });
  }
}
```

`about.component.spec.ts`:

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { AboutComponent } from './about.component';
import { AboutService } from './about.service';

fdescribe('62700708', () => {
  let component: AboutComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AboutComponent>;
  let aboutServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<AboutService>;
  const data = '20/04/2019';

  beforeEach(() => {
    aboutServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('AboutService', ['getAboutInfo']);
    aboutServiceSpy.getAboutInfo.and.returnValue(of(data));

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AboutComponent],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [{ provide: AboutService, useValue: aboutServiceSpy }],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AboutComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('when OnInit invoked through service data will return to infoList ', () => {
    expect(aboutServiceSpy.getAboutInfo).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(component.dataList).toEqual(['20', '04', '2019']);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

[image]